# Blindness spell on earth elemental

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters

Can an earth elemental be blinded using the blindness cleric spell.  I tried it and even though it failed the saving through my DM said it appeared to have no effect on its ability to attack.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question! I never thought about it before, and now that I have I'm pretty sure I've gotten it wrong in the past.

Answer (score 10):

### It's complicated, but by RAW, the Earth Elemental should probably have suffered the penalties of the Blinded condition.

What makes it complicated is that Earth Elementals have Tremorsense. Tremorsense is defined on page 9 of the Monster Manual as:

> A monster with tremorsense can detect and pinpoint
>   the origin of vibrations within a specific radius,
>   provided that the monster and the source of the
>   vibrations are in contact with the same ground or
>   substance. Tremorsense can’t be used to detect flying or
>   incorporeal creatures. Many burrowing creatures, such
>   as ankhegs and umber hulks, have this special sense.

So the Earth Elemental would certainly have known where its targets were in order to attack them. However, preventing creatures from seeing is not the only thing the Blinded condition does.

> - A blinded creature can’t see and automatically fails any
>     ability check that requires sight.
> - Attack rolls against the creature have advantage, and
>     the creature’s attack rolls have disadvantage.

Earth Elementals aren't immune to the Blinded condition, and while Tremorsense means that the first bullet point wouldn't really affect their ability to attack, the second still would.

### "But Miniman! If the Earth Elemental can still tell where its targets are, why would it have disadvantage?"

On page 194 of the PHB, there is a section on Unseen Attackers and Targets. The important bit for our purposes is this:

> When you attack a target that you can’t see, you have
>   disadvantage on the attack roll. **This is true whether
>   you’re guessing the target’s location or you’re targeting a
>   creature you can hear but not see.**

The Earth Elemental, using its Tremorsense, can pinpoint the location of its target, and doesn't have to guess which square it's in. However, it still can't see the creature, and should suffer disadvantage.

Finally, you didn't ask, but using the same reasoning, you should also have had advantage on attacks against it.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding Tremorsense on a 5e Earth Elemental.  Can you please link or cite where it says they have that ability?  I know I'm probably just overlooking it.

Comment: @Thorborn762 Their entry in any of the Monster Manual, the SRD, or the DM's Basic Rules.

Comment: Ohh I don't have my MM on me, but looking at the Hyptertext SRD [link](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/elemental.htm) I don't see it?

Comment: @Thorborn762 It helps if you look at [something actually published by Wizards](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf).

Comment: awesome, didn't realize that wasn't a good website, thanks for the link.  Not so much for your smartass attitude, but thanks nonetheless

Answer (score 2):

#### A creature with Tremorsense would not be blinded within its Tremorsense radius. Outside that radius however, it would suffer the effects of blindness normally.

*(For the case of the Earth Elemental, within 60 ft creatures on the ground would have no advantages, but creatures more than 60 ft away or those flying would gain the blinded benefits as normal.)*

In Miniman's answer he claims that you would have advantage on a blinded creature. However, Tremorsense is a **more specific rule** (same as blindsight) when dealing with a blinded creature.

Additionally he cites a passage regarding Unseen attackers:

> This is true whether you're guessing the targets location or you're targeting a creature **you can hear but not see.** (PHB p. 194)

However, the creature with Tremorsense is using an ability that can accurately pinpoint a creature's location and movement, that is not, or not necessarily, hearing, and again is a **specific rule overriding normal vision rules.**

**Note that with Miniman's reading of this rule, Blindsight would also be affected by the Blinded condition the same way,** which seems like a clear violation of **RAI**, if not the general **RAW** of "**specific beats general.**"

**Blindsight** - Effectively grants you line of sight vision within a radius that does not rely on sight in any way. Outside of this you have vision as normal (or lack thereof), and you cannot see through walls, and only minorly around corners. (*Note some DMs may rule this lets you see through walls as well as there isn't a specific rule saying you cannot.*) This type of vision ignores visual illusions, and spells like Mirror Image.

**Tremorsense** - Effectively grants you non-line of sight vision of things within a radius when in contact with the same ground as the creature, or in contact with something that is in contact with the ground. You can see anything as long as it is within the radius and in contact with the ground, including through walls and around corners. Flying creatures and creatures outside this radius are effectively invisible to **this sense**. This sense ignores illusions which are nontangible, and spells such as Mirror Image.